# Converting Jsonp to Json in different methods

Tags: ruby, json, jsonp

I been trying to use JSONP data in a json format in a ruby project.

From your experiences how did you address this?

Comment: It perfectly valid to build question and answer in SO but you must do it properly, that is separating the question from the answer.

Comment: Alright, I thought it will be like high five-ing yourself, you got it boss

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking). By the way, the regex tag should be removed as it isn't related to the question but to your answer.

Comment: fair enough, consider it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, one way is to use this regex to filter out the function callback name:

```
/(\{.*\})/m
```

or the lazy way would be find the index of the first occurrence of "(" and just substring it with last character, which would be a ")" .

I been trying to look for answers on here, didn't get a solid answer, hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

JSONP is easy to handle. It's just JSON in a minor wrapper, and that wrapper is easy to strip off:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

URL = 'http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=epitome'
jsonp = open(URL).read
```

`jsonp` now contains the result in JSONP format:

```
jsonp[0, 3] # => "a({"
jsonp[-11 ... -1] # => "},200,null"
```

Those extraneous parts, `a{` and `,200,null"` are the trouble spots when passing the data to JSON for parsing, so we strip them.

A simple, greedy, regex is all that's needed. `/{.+}/` will find everything wrapped by the outermost curly-braces and return it, which is all the JSON needs:

```
data = JSON.parse(jsonp[/{.+}/])

data['query'] # => "epitome"
data['primaries'].size # => 1
```